# Dynamic Schema name in SQL based on database-name Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-schema, code-reuse

I have a DML statement "Simple update statement"  that i need to execute in Different Oracle Environment (DEV,SIT,QA,PROD). As of Now im hard coding the Schema Name in Alter Session Command and Running the DML statement. So i need to maintain 4 different scripts across the environment.
Is there a way i can get the Database name on which the script is Running, from the database Name i can use If Else Condition to Choose between the Schema and assign it to the ALTER SESSION COMMAND?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the name from the [`v$database` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_1096.htm). How you translate that to an `alter session` command depends on your client and how you're connecting.

For example, in SQL*Plus you could do:

```
column x_schema new_value y_schema noprint
set termout off

select case name
  when 'DEVDB' then 'DEVSCHEMA'
  when 'PRODDB' then 'PRODSCHEMA'
  ...
  end as x_schema
from v$database;

alter session set current_schema = &y_schema;
set termout on
```

The first query uses the DB name to determine a schema name; the `column` command makes that column alias `x_schema` available later as substitution variable `&y_schema`. Then that is used in the `alter`. The `set termout` is optional but will hide the query if it's run as part of a script (though then I guess the `noprint` is a bit pointless).

You could base your `case` on `global_name.global_name` if you prefer, or even `sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME')`.

Of course, you could also just pass the schema name in as a positional parameter when you run the DML script instead. It's unusual, I think, for the schema name to be different for the same application in different databases, but this should work if that is the situation you have.

Comment: I got the below Error when i tried to execute the statement.

'SQL*Plus command ignored: column v_schema new value y_schema noprint 
  
X_SCHEMA
DEV_SCHEMA
   
ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier'

Comment: @balaji - sorry, I clearly hadn't tested that, and managed to have three errors in that short snippet - two in the `column` command, somehow. Very poor show. I've updated with tested (!) code.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. it now works. Thanks for the Information and thanks for introducing me to "COLUMN" functions..

Answer (score 0):

To get the current schema name:

```
select user from dual
```

Is this what you're after?